# How do I dump entire dom structure using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am new at selenium and python, and I am having problems finding the best way to identify the page elements I need for my automation.
I have a webpage with a lot of javascript on it.  When I use firefox's inspect element for the username field in the login form, I see an input tag with an id, but when I ask selenium to find that id it says it can't be found.
I want to double-check that what I saw in firefox is actually what selenium is seeing, so I tried:

```
with open("login.html","w") s f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

I see no input elements at all in the resulting file.

Based on another stackoverflow question I tried:

```
DOM=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
with open("login.html","w") as f:
    f.write(DOM)
```

Still no input elements.

Is there a better way to see all the dom elements and/or find the correct xpath/ids to sue for my selenium script ?

Comment: Check whether `form` located inside an `iframe`

Comment: @anderson, there are not iframes in teh html as obtained by driver.page_source.

Comment: No. Not in page source. Check DOM of page completely rendered in browser: right click on input field -> Inspect element -> Check ancestors

Comment: Looking at the page using firefox's inspector, it doesn't look like there is an iframe anywhere in the entire dom.  However, I did notice that there are refferences to oraclejet views and models and templates, so I don't know how those get rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Try get all body HTML by `document.body.innerHTM`

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
with open("login.html","w") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: When I use the code you suggested, I get the same results I got before where I see a lot fo divs and I can see a refference to an oracle jet view binding tied to a template and the json object giving the attributes for the template, but no actual html generated by the view/template.

Comment: Have you tried add a long sleep/wait before the `driver.execute_script(...)`, just to confirm it's not due to page not complete load.  And please show HTML of the page if you can see them when you open the page in Browser manually

Answer (score 1):

@yong, your suggestion of adding a long sleep before the execute_script was the right answer.  Now I can see the entire html source in the file I created.

In addition now my PageObject code works to fill in the login form and submit it.  I do another sleep and then print the pageurl and title to make sure I have moved on to the next page.

Final code:

```
driver = webdriver..Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_time(60)
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(60)
print("URL: "+driver.current_url)
print("Title: "driver.title)
page=LoginPage(driver)
page.username="username"
page.password="password"
page.signin_button.click()
time.sleep(60)
print("URL: "+driver.current_url)
print("Title: "+driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Thank you everyone for the suggestions.